# Can videos be played without controls?

Tags: iphone, video

I'm planning on making a game for the iPhone and want to have the background constantly animated. I figured rather than looping a series of images, I'd play a video. Is it possible for me to play a video (with no controls popping up), and have graphics overtop of it (the actual game)? Or would I just be better off with looping images?

(I figured SO would be a better place to ask this than Game Development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using AVFoundation, or even the MPMoviePlayerController with the controls property turned off.

You can have anything you like overlaying the video.  The performance for that is much better in iOS4 than earlier OS versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MPMoviePlayerController and set the control style to none.

[MPMoviePlayerController control style](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW31) and [MPMoviePlayerController control style list](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/MPMovieControlStyleDefault)